# golang mgo marshalling bson

Tags: mongodb, go, marshalling, bson, mgo

I have a structure like this:

```
type data_to_store struct {
    Data     some_custom_structure       `json:"Data" bson:"Data"`
    MoreData   another_custom_structure   `json:"more_data" bson:"More_Data"`
}
```

creating an object that uses this struct:

```
Data := data_to_store {
    Data:     some_custom_struct_object,
    MoreData:   another_custom_struct_object,
}
```

And I'm trying to insert it into db like that:

```
session, _ := mgo.Dial("localhost")
defer session.Close()
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
collection := session.DB("test_database").C("test_collection")
collection.Insert(&Data)
```

And it does store, but it turns out to be inserted like this:

```
{ "lol": "rofl",
  "lmao": "kek",
  }
} { "blah": "blahblah",
  "ololo": 2,
}
```

Is there a way to make it be stored like the following?

```
"data": { "lol": "rofl",
  "lmao": "kek",
  }
}, "more_data" { "blah": "blahblah",
  "ololo": 2,
}
```

Marshalling data doesn't help in this endeavour, or I'm doing it wrong:

```
data, _ := bson.Marshal(&replay)
collection.Insert(&data)
```

Comment: Your code is not valid, can you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can troubleshoot the actual issue?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Code does indeed had some issues.

Here is the corrected version: https://play.golang.org/p/nrGwyMCMJm

But I actually need to note that I simplified it a bit, by replacing custom structs with strings.

Comment: When I run the code from the snippet it inserts a document with "data" and "more_data" fields: `{
    "_id" : ...,
    "Data" : "some_custom_struct_object",
    "More_Data" : "another_custom_struct_object"
}`

Comment: Yes, that's why I simplified it with just strings.
The reason for that is that these structs comes from elsewhere.
Or more specifically it is objects of this library: https://github.com/icza/s2prot

Comment: Fair enough, but you need to describe the problem in the question itself. The code you provided meets your expectation, so there is nothing to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this below is the Json structure that you want to store in Mongo:

```
{
"data": [{
        "lol": "rofl"
    },
    {
        "lmao": "kek"
    }
],
"more_data": [{
        "blah": "blahblah"
    },
    {
        "ololo": 2
        }
    ]}
```

You need these type of Go struct:

```
type Data struct {
    Key  string `json:"key,omitempty"`
    Value string `json:"value,omitempty"`
}

type DataToStore struct {
   Data []Data `json:"data"`
   MoreData []Data  `json:"more_data"`
}
```

You can use this online [tool](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to convert json into go struct.